# Save to Gallery Remote File download in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been trying to download a remote file in an ionic app but it seems like is not working for me and it's not given me an error

I have tried using different approached but all effort avail abortive and even the snippet provided on the ionic webpage isn't working either. I don't know what i am missing on my code. I do like saving the files on the gallery of the mobile device and i have tried 'Downloads' as the targeted folder and it's not working

```
download(filename) {
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
let name = filename.split("/");
let length = name.length;
const url ="http://vvvvvvvv.com/dashboardksi/api/uploads/" + name[length - 1];
console.log("clicked", name);
fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + name[length - 1], true).then(entry => {
      console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
      console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    }
  );}
```

Comment: simple solution open the file `url` in a new `blank` tab using `window.open()`

Comment: do you mean something like this ??  `this.inappbrowser.create(link, "_system", "location=yes");`

Comment: `window.open(url , '_blank');`

Comment: isn't possible to download it in the app without opening a new window?? cos on a new window it won't give me the option to save